# How to make asp.net control conditionally display based on user role?

Tags: asp.net, role

I looked at the other questions concerning this topic, but could not get the solution to work, here is what I have from the other answer:

```
<asp:Panel ID="userOptionsPan" runat="server" Visible='<%# User.IsInRole("User") %>'>
    User options pan test
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="employeeOptionsPan" runat="server" Visible='<%# User.IsInRole("Employee") %>'>
    Employee options pan test
</asp:Panel>
```

I log in with just the User role but both panel are still visible.  How do I fix this?

I do not get any error messages, it just does not work.

Comment: Set visibility from codebehind, then you can also debug `User.IsInRole("Employee")`. Are you using a custom role-provider? What membership provider do you use(fe. `SqlMembershipProvider`)? Show us your web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a server call on a server property. This won't work , normally you use <%# %> tags to set html or javascript data, not server data.

You can either set the Style attribute (which is a html property) or you could set the visiblity on page_load like this :

```
userOptionsPan.Visible = user.IsInRole("User");
```